# Creating password for a Python file without encryption

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-pro

I am attempting to create a password to lock a python file for a script tool I am building out in ArcGIS Pro. I am not worried about the password being visible in the script itself, since I am able to password lock the script in ArcGIS Pro already. I have scoured the internet looking for a simple example script, but have been unable to find one because most of the posts I am seeing are concerned with encryption and security.

Does anyone know of a way to simply add a password with arcpy.GetParameterAsText() for user input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign the password parameter to a variable, then use an if statement to test the password:

```
pw = arcpy.GetParameterAsText()
if pw == 'your_password': 
    do stuff
    do more stuff  
else: 
    print('Incorrect Password!!!')
```

Comment: Don't forget the appropriate datatype [GPStringHidden](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/defining-parameter-data-types-in-a-python-toolbox.htm#:~:text=String%20Hidden-,GPStringHidden)